# unable to send mail using laravel php

Tags: php, laravel, email, laravel-5, smtp

I am unable to send a test mail. I am using laravel php.

my .env file:

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=mailtrap.io
MAIL_PORT=2525
MAIL_USERNAME=ca**********4b
MAIL_PASSWORD=04**********7b
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
```

my mail.php:

```
'driver' => env('MAIL_DRIVER', 'smtp'),
'host' => env('MAIL_HOST', 'mailtrap.io'),
'port' => env('MAIL_PORT', 2525),
'from' => ['address' =>'******@gmail.com', 'name' => '****'],
'encryption' => env('MAIL_ENCRYPTION', 'tls'),
'username' => env('ca**********4b'),
'password' => env('04**********7b'),
'sendmail' => '/usr/sbin/sendmail -bs',
```

my controller:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Request;
use Response;
use App\Users;
use Mail;

class MailController extends Controller
{
public function basic_email(){
  $data = array('name'=>"Virat Gandhi");

  Mail::send(['text'=>'welcome'], $data, function($message) {
     $message->to('******@gmail.com', '*****')->subject
        ('Laravel Basic Testing Mail');
     $message->from('"******@gmail.com','Virat Gandhi');
  });
  return "Basic Email Sent. Check your inbox.";
    }
  }
```

i am getting this error:

> Swift_TransportException in AbstractSmtpTransport.php line 383:
>   Expected response code 250 but got code "530", with message "530 5.7.1 Authentication required
>   "

tried clearing cache by `php artisan config:cache`

what do i need to try more?

Comment: in .env file, use MAIL_PORT=587 instead of 2525,in mail.php file use 'port' => env('MAIL_PORT', 587),'username' => env('MAIL_USERNAME'),'password' => env('MAIL_PASSWORD'),

Comment: thank you @Borna changing username and password did the trick. The port had to be 2525.

Comment: great..can u mark my comment useful?? then it will be useful for other users

Comment: how can i do that? i cant find any options. @Borna

Comment: put your mouse on my comment,then u will see flag and uparrow,then click uparrow

Comment: if you couldn't see it earlier, i actually upvoted it :).

Answer (score 1):

I believe it's gonna be firewall issue, have you tried to connect to `gmail` provider ? it's a good way to catch the error

Comment: Thank you for your help! but i solved it the other way.